# how do you know which python egg is enforcing a constraint in buildout?

Tags: python, buildout

For instance the following is built with `bin/buildout -Nvv`

```
...
Getting required 'grokcore.component>=2.5'
  required by five.grok 1.3.2.
  required by grokcore.viewlet 1.11.
Picked: grokcore.component = 2.5
Getting required 'grokcore.annotation'
  required by five.grok 1.3.2.
Picked: grokcore.annotation = 1.3
The constraint, 0.4, is not consistent with the requirement, 'five.localsitemanager>2.0dev'.
While:
  Installing instance.
Error: Bad constraint 0.4 five.localsitemanager>2.0dev
```

The constraint `five.localsitemanager>2.0dev` does not seem to be enforced by grokcore.annotation (see https://github.com/zopefoundation/grokcore.annotation/blob/master/setup.py) But how do I find out which egg is actually enforcing this?

Comment: Is it still relevant? If not, perhaps it's time to close the question...

Comment: The problem still occurs from time to time, so the question can stay open. The packages change, but the problem remains.

Comment: Check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827258/find-requirement-specs-in-a-plone-buildout-setup (eggdeps)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very old question, but I had the same problem yesterday and [my colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27401/reinout-van-rees) found a way to solve the problem. So I thought I might as well post it here.

All your buildout eggs are either in an `eggs` folder in your project or in a `.buildout` folder in your home folder, including development eggs. In each egg you'll find a `requires.txt` file with the requirements for the egg. This means you can do a find/grep on the `.buildout/eggs` folder for the specific constraint to find out which package is enforcing it.

So in your case I would suggest you go to the eggs directory (in my case `~/.buildout/eggs`) and then do:

```
find .|grep requires.txt|xargs grep 2.0dev
```

That should find the egg that's enforcing the constraint.

In my case I was upgrading to Django 1.7 and there was one package with the constraint `'Django >= 1.4, < 1.7'`. So executing `find .|grep requires.txt|xargs grep 1.7` found the problematic egg.

Comment: An addition: the `~/.buildout/eggs/` folder is only used if you enable it. Otherwise you have to look in the `eggs/` folder inside the project directory.

Comment: Second comment: the `< 1.7` can be problematic as it can also be written as `<1.7` (without spaces) and so. Searching for the package name in the various `EGG-INFO/requires.txt` files is quicker. Something like `find . | grep requires.txt | xargs grep -i the-package-name `

Comment: Thanks for the additions @reinout-van-rees! I just looked in my `.bash_history` and that is indeed the command you used on my `.buildout/eggs` folder. I guess I wasn't paying close enough attention yesterday. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me ... but I found it into the `parts/` directory. So it is better to run the grep command from the project directory root (the parent of `eggs/` folder) when the folder `~/.buildout/eggs/` is not used.