# How to resolve conflicts between dependencies in Plone?

Tags: python, plone

I am writing an add-on for Plone 5.1. I have added dependency to my add-on's `setup.py` `install_requires` parameter. I have also added my add-on (esperonus.vimeo) to Plone's `buildout.cfg`. However, upon running buildout, I get this error:

```
ryselis@ryselis-All-Series:~/Plone/zinstance$ bin/buildout -c develop.cfg
mr.developer: Queued 'esperonus.vimeo_plone' for checkout.
mr.developer: Filesystem package 'esperonus.vimeo_plone' doesn't need a checkout.
Develop: '/home/ryselis/Plone/zinstance/src/esperonus.vimeo_plone'
Updating _mr.developer.
Installing instance.
Version and requirements information containing certifi:
  [versions] constraint on certifi: 2017.11.5
  Requirement of tuspy==0.2.1: certifi==2017.7.27.1
  Requirement of requests>=2.4.0: certifi>=2017.4.17
While:
  Installing instance.
Error: The requirement ('certifi==2017.7.27.1') is not allowed by your [versions] constraint (2017.11.5)
```

It looks like VimeoPy requires different version of certifi than tuspy (I guess this is Plone's dependency?). Is there anything I could do to add VimeoPy to my add-on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find requirement specs in a Plone buildout setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827258/find-requirement-specs-in-a-plone-buildout-setup)

Comment: In short you want to execute `grep -r --include=*.cfg certifi` of the commandline from within your instance-directory, to search for config-files containing the error-causing package (here: "certifi"), and if the found line pins it to a certain version, remove that line and rerun buildout.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that you have pinned version in your buildout configuration which are di8ffer from what a packages want's to install. You can remove the pinnings from the buildout configuration accept you have a reason for it.
New buildout versions usually have an option called "update-versions-file" which points to the buildout config file with the list of versions. Buildout will add all picked versions, which where not pinned and add them for you, so that you can rebuild this configuration later with exact the same versions.
But these pinnings are save to remove, especially if you have packages requiring diffent versions.